# How to customize docstring generation in pycharm?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm, python-sphinx, docstring

In VsCode, I add this to `.vscode/settings.json`

```
    "autoDocstring.docstringFormat": "sphinx",
    "autoDocstring.generateDocstringOnEnter": true,
    "autoDocstring.includeExtendedSummary": true,
    "autoDocstring.guessTypes": true,
    "autoDocstring.customTemplatePath": ".vscode/sphinx.mustache",
```

and then in `.vscode/sphinx.mustache`

```
{{! Sphinx Docstring Template }}
{{summaryPlaceholder}}

{{extendedSummaryPlaceholder}}

{{#args}}
:param {{typePlaceholder}} {{var}}: {{descriptionPlaceholder}}
{{/args}}
{{#kwargs}}
:param {{typePlaceholder}}{{#default}}, optional {{var}}: {{descriptionPlaceholder}}, defaults to {{/default}}{{&default}}
{{/kwargs}}
{{#exceptionsExist}}

{{#exceptions}}
:raises {{type}}: {{descriptionPlaceholder}}
{{/exceptions}}
{{/exceptionsExist}}
{{#yieldsExist}}

{{#yields}}
:yield: {{descriptionPlaceholder}}
:rtype: {{typePlaceholder}}
{{/yields}}
{{/yieldsExist}}
{{#returnsExist}}

{{#returns}}
:return: {{descriptionPlaceholder}}
:rtype: {{typePlaceholder}}
{{/returns}}
{{/returnsExist}}

:Example:

>>>
>>>
>>>

.. note:: [can be useful to emphasize important features]
.. seealso:: [can be useful to link to other parts of the doc for example :class:`MainClass2`]
.. warning:: [can be useful to document warnings]
.. todo:: [can be useful to request a todo from the user]
```

How to customize docstring in pycharm? In VsCode, I customize it with sphinx.mustache and even push it to the remote repository so that it can be used by other developers of the team as well? Is there such a possibility in Pycharm?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70962034/how-to-choose-format-of-rest-docstring-stubs-in-pycharm/70966441#70966441

and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12327

Seems that it is not possible and it is a feature request

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12327#focus=Comments-27-5736306.0-0