# How to choose format of reST docstring stubs in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, restructuredtext, docstring

In [JetBrain's example](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html#example) for docstring in Pycharm, it is mentioned that:

```
Note that for reStructuredText it's possible to specify types in two formats:

:param param_type param_name: parameter description (type description is on the same line as the parameter description).

:type param_name: param_type (type description is on a separate line)
```

I want to make my pycharm autogenerate the second variant, not the first one?
Currently, it is even not even adding the type

```
def foo(a: str, b: int = 1) -> str:
    """

    :param a: 
    :param b: 
    :return: 
    """
    return a + str(b)
```

a related question is: [How to customize docstring generation in pycharm and share the template through git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961141/how-to-customize-docstring-generation-in-pycharm-and-share-the-template-through)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, in spite of the documentation mentioning both formats, it appears it is not possible to switch between the two styles. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12327

You can enable the second style (which I think you want) by checking the following option:
`Editor - General - Smart Keys - Python` check `Insert type placeholders in the documentation comment stub`. (or use the Settings search and search for `comment stub`)

Very unintuitive and many people have been requesting improvements to this functionality in PyCharm. Ideally, you'd want to be able to provide a custom sphinx.mustache docstring template of this style:

```
{{! Sphinx Docstring Template }}
{{summaryPlaceholder}}

{{extendedSummaryPlaceholder}}

{{#args}}
:param {{var}}: {{descriptionPlaceholder}}
{{/args}}
{{#kwargs}}
:param {{var}}: {{descriptionPlaceholder}}
{{/kwargs}}
{{#exceptions}}
:raises {{type}}: {{descriptionPlaceholder}}
{{/exceptions}}
{{#returns}}
:return: {{descriptionPlaceholder}}
{{/returns}}
{{#yields}}
:yield: {{descriptionPlaceholder}}
{{/yields}}
```

(example taken from here https://github.com/executablebooks/markdown-it-py/blob/master/docstring.fmt.mustache)

But again, that is currently not supported in PyCharm - feel free to comment and vote on the linked issue, and perhaps it gets some attention.

Comment: I enabled type placeholder but I prefer `:param int bar:` not `:param bar:` and then `:type int:` because I think the first one is more readable